# Where exactly was Obi-Wan going?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, obi-wan-kenobi

In Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith, following his fight with General Grievous, Obi-Wan is handed his lightsaber by Commander Cody, remarks that they have a battle to win and then just starts climbing the sinkhole away from the battle.

Where exactly was he headed? Was he heading to another section of the battle or to the surface, and for what reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kenobi is riding his dragonmount "into the battle" for the city. There are, apparently, still plenty of droids and not nearly enough clone troops to make the fight an overwhelming certainty.

> Ah. Well, yes. It has been a … stressful day.” He waved out at Pau City. “But we still have a battle to win.”
> ...
> Kenobi nodded and spoke to his mount, and the great beast overleapt the clone commander **on its way down into the battle**.
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novelization))</sup></sub>

and

> The trouble with droids is that they can’t think, Obi-Wan told himself
> as **he hacked his way through the battle droids that still clogged the
> sinkhole tunnel city on Utapau**. An army made up of living beings would
> have seen how badly outnumbered they were, and given up. The droids
> just kept on fighting.
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Junior novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>